# gradle 'build' task confusion

Tags: gradle

Hi I have multi project gradle setup

```
-root_project
|-sub_project1
|-sub_project2
|-sub_project3
```

All works great but one thing drives me crazy. In my build script:

```
defaultTasks 'build' <- this works just fine

task buildroom (description: 'This task is invoked by build room script, invokes default task plus publishes artifacts') { 
//    dependsOn('build') <-- this doesn't work

// alternative 
dependsOn(":sub_project1:build")
dependsOn(":sub_project2:build")
```

when i call from command line 'gradlew' <- default task gets executed

when i call from command line 'gradlew tasks' <- task under 'all task runnable from root project' i see 'build'

but when i try to add dependsOn('build'), dependsOn(':build') or dependsOn(':root:build') it tells me

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':tasks'.
>
> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':buildroom'.

'base' plugin adds 'assemble', and 'clean' task but not build...

any tips?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `build` task is declared by the `java-base` plugin. It's likely that your root project doesn't (directly or indirectly) apply `java-base` and therefore doesn't have a `build` task. This is why `dependsOn("build")`, which adds a task dependency on a task named `build` in the *same project*, eventually causes an error. `defaultTasks` is different in that:

- It only accepts task names (whereas `dependsOn` also accepts task paths and `Task` objects).
- Its task names get resolved to tasks as if the task names had been entered on the command line. In other words, all projects are searched for a task with the given name, and the set of matching tasks is returned.

Comment: thanks Peter, now knowing that for detaultTasks **all subprojects are searched for a task with the given name, and the set of matching tasks is returned.** it all makes sense. thanks you for answer.