# What are list of tasks that ConnectedAndroidTest executes?

Tags: android, android-testing

I want to understand more about ConnectedAndroidTest Gradle task. I see that it is used to install the application and test apks and run the tests.

But what are the individual steps that it does? (gradle tasks if any)

"gradle build" seems to generate the Application apk. What task generates the test apk? And how does it(ConnectedAndroidTest) install the application and test apk? And how does it start the tests?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My first SO answer, please be gentle ;)

> But what are the individual steps that it does? (gradle tasks if any)

So if you want a high-level overview of what **tasks** ConnectedAndroidTest depends on, just running `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` or `./gradlew cAT` (without the `-q` option) will output the name of each task that `cAT` depends on before it itself is executed. The task itself can't have other tasks inside it, but can depend on others coming before it.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535258/gradle-build-task-confusion) answer, the `gradle build` task is actually something java related, and isn't what's responsible for building the test apk. Instead, it's the `assembleAndroidTest` task that comes right before `connectedAndroidTest` that does it. You are right about the `connectedAndroidTest` though, it actually installs and runs the test apk. But I'll come to how in a bit. The rest of my answer is goes into more detail than is necessary to use the task effectively, but is useful if you want to understand how it works.

**Some background** 
Like many other Android gradle plug-in tasks, connectedAndroidTest is actually put together at some point in the execution phase because of the different build variants (debug, release, flavour 1, flavor 2 etc.). So `connectedAndroidTest` isn't available to you in the configuration phase (when most of your build script logic is executed). Instead, once it's built, it's set as the `connectedInstrumentTest` **property** (basically, a field) of the `testVariants` property in the `android` object.

As an example for clarification, if you want to access this task to manipulate it somehow (maybe add an `Action` to the end of it), you can do something like this in your `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
  testVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.connectedInstrumentTest.doLast {
      println "This will be executed right after our connectedInstrumentTest!"
      println "The name of the test type: $connectedInstrumentTest.name"
      println "The type of test $connectedInstrumentTest.class"       
    }
  }
}
```

And then run `./gradlew -q cAT`

So here, I'm adding an action to the end of whatever task has been built and assigned to the `connectedInstrumentTest` property, which is nested fairly deep in the `android` object. This task will be likely be`connectedDebugAndroidTest` or something similar.

**What's the task doing?** 
Now, from the type property I put in the last println, we can see that the class of the task is actually `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask_Decorated`. To be honest, I'm not too sure yet where that `_Decorated` part comes from, but a google search for the rest of the class name provides us with the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/69c4b95102b4b9862bfba68b3eaf5b7537a705ee/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/tasks/DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.groovy) for the base class of the task.

The main `Action` of the task is called `runTests()` and shows you more or less how the task accomplishes what it does. If you follow the source code around a bit, you eventually find that the `adb pm install` command will be used to install the apk.

Although I couldn't quite find it, I suspect that somewhere else the adb command `adb shell am instrument -w com.package.name/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` command is being used to finally drive the tests.

So I hope that wasn't too confusing - I learnt most of this very recently so some things might not be 100%. I would suggest working through the gradle docs, in particular how to create a custom plugin and a custom task, and also check out the [Android gradle plug-in](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) tools documentation.

Comment: So does `connectedAndroidTest` actually run `build` and `compile`?

Comment: `@IgorGanapolsky, `connectedAndroidTest` depends directly on `assembleDebug` (assembles debug APK) and `assembleDebugAndroidTest` (assembles test APK). Those two tasks compile everything. There are also `installDebug` and `installDebugAndroidTest` tasks, but I'm not clear exactly where they are on the dependency tree. They must happen after the `assemble*` tasks, and before the tests actually run (of course), but I'm not sure exactly where.

Comment: Why does ./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest uninstall my app when it's done? This is driving me crazy!

Comment: me too @Phlip - did you figure this out? It is breaking my test runs!

Comment: I used primitive gradlew commands to test without uninstalling. they are a pain to run because they expose more than the usual amount of bugs in adb, but I wrote them up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57433975/gradlew-test-connectedandroidtest-erases-my-getfilesdir-folder/60174578#60174578

Answer (score 2):

To answer the more general question "what are the list of tasks that task `<taskName>` executes?", there are two simple ways to find that out for any given task.

**The first is:**

```
./gradlew tasks --all | grep <taskName>
```

where `<taskName>` should be replaced with whatever task you care about. E.g., `./gradlew tasks --all | grep connectedDebugAndroidTest`. Note that I'm piping through `grep` to save myself the trouble of manually sifting through the list of all tasks.

**The second is:**

Use the [task-tree](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.dorongold.task-tree) plugin. Once applied, usage looks like this:

```
./gradlew <taskName> taskTree
```

Or, as I usually prefer it:

```
./gradlew <taskName> taskTree --no-repeat -quiet
```

The latter option makes the output a bit less cluttered.

Answer (score 1):

You could also execute `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest --dry-run` which will list all the tasks it'd run, but won't run any. `--dry-run` does the same for any gradle task that you want to analyze.