# Unit testing and espresso using only an APK (no source code available)

Tags: android, unit-testing, command-line, apk, android-espresso

Is there a Gradle command-line command to run unit tests and espresso ui tests using only an apk(debug or release)? Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest`

It requires an debug .apk file in directory `{project_folder}/app/build/outputs/apk`

If you don't have any .apk there use  in terminal ./gradlew assembleDebug

If you have `Permission denied` info please put: `chmod u+x gradlew' and then use above intructions.

Read this: [What are list of tasks thats ConnectedAndroidTest executes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713525/what-are-list-of-tasks-thats-connectedandroidtest-executes)

I recommend you also for instrumentation tests using `monkey` framework.

If you have any question, please free to ask

Comment: Thanks for replying. But that will generate a new debug apk. you also need the source code. What I was looking for was that you have a debug apk, you take that debug apk to some other folder and run android espresso UI test using some command.

Comment: Read please about Continuous Integration and configuring Jenkins/Hudson for Android. I think it may help you to deal with it. Yes, however you made a debug .apk you still need to be connected with Android SDK, so my solution is partially but ... the nearest you would be have a CI server which would made a debug app and run the test

Comment: I think there's no solution to make it without Android SDK. According to my experience, only `monkey` can make Android tests without source code