# How can I set connectedAndroidTest on build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I need to set the connectedAndroidTest on build.gradle instead of run a command line. How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713525/what-are-list-of-tasks-that-connectedandroidtest-executes

Comment: Thanks for the link. There is another way to generate report (app\build\reports\androidTests\connected\...) without executing the command line?

Comment: Well, I mean I can think of how to do it in VS Code (with the gradle plugin) but then it's just running the commandline in the background.

Comment: When I run in this way, the report is not being generated :(