# Executing Espresso Tests in Browserstack

Tags: android, automation, ui-automation, android-espresso, browserstack

I am planning to execute Android UI Automation tests on Browserstack device in cloud. In my local dev environment, The test is executed using `./gradlew connectedMockDebugAndroidTest` in my local environment. My feature files and mock json response files are kept inside assets folder. And it gets compiled and added to the apk.

How do I execute these tests on a Browserstack device using `./gradlew connectedMockDebugAndroidTest` command?

I went through their documentation [here](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/espresso/getting-started), but it says to upload test suite. Is it not possible to execute test on browserstack using connectedMockDebugAndroidTest?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is currently possible based on this:
[What are list of tasks that ConnectedAndroidTest executes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713525/what-are-list-of-tasks-that-connectedandroidtest-executes)

There is no way to establish a connection to a remote cloud server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When using BrowserStack for Android UI Automation tests, you typically `need to upload your test suite and associated files to their cloud-based service`. The **connectedMockDebugAndroidTest** command you mentioned is typically used for running tests locally or on connected devices/emulators.

BrowserStack requires you to upload your test suite and any associated files (such as feature files and mock JSON response files) to their cloud-based service as mentioned in the [doc](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/espresso/getting-started) you have in your question..

Once your test suite is uploaded, you can trigger the execution of the tests on a BrowserStack device by invoking the appropriate command or API provided by BrowserStack.