# shadow plugin in gradle is not working - gradle build does not build a fat jar

Tags: scala, gradle, shadowjar

I have the following `build.gradle` content:

```
group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.1"
    }
}


apply plugin: 'scala'   
apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"
sourceCompatibility = java_version


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // my dependencies:
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: "spark-sql_$scala_major", version: spark_version
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

The problem is that running `gradle build` isn't creating a fat jar.

Looking at the task dependencies by running `gradle tasks --all` shows that the `shadowJar` task exists, but the `build` task is not dependent on it:

```
:tasks

------------------------------------------------------------
All tasks runnable from root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Build tasks
-----------
assemble - Assembles the outputs of this project.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend on it.
buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.
classes - Assembles main classes.
clean - Deletes the build directory.
jar - Assembles a jar archive containing the main classes.
testClasses - Assembles test classes.

Build Setup tasks
-----------------
init - Initializes a new Gradle build.
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files.

Documentation tasks
-------------------
javadoc - Generates Javadoc API documentation for the main source code.
scaladoc - Generates Scaladoc for the main source code.

Help tasks
----------
buildEnvironment - Displays all buildscript dependencies declared in root project 'scalaGradleHW'.
components - Displays the components produced by root project 'scalaGradleHW'. [incubating]
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'scalaGradleHW'.
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'scalaGradleHW'.
dependentComponents - Displays the dependent components of components in root project 'scalaGradleHW'. [incubating]
help - Displays a help message.
model - Displays the configuration model of root project 'scalaGradleHW'. [incubating]
projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project 'scalaGradleHW'.
properties - Displays the properties of root project 'scalaGradleHW'.
tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'scalaGradleHW'.

Shadow tasks
------------
knows - Do you know who knows?
shadowJar - Create a combined JAR of project and runtime dependencies

Verification tasks
------------------
check - Runs all checks.
test - Runs the unit tests.

Other tasks
-----------
compileJava - Compiles main Java source.
compileScala - Compiles the main Scala source.
compileTestJava - Compiles test Java source.
compileTestScala - Compiles the test Scala source.
processResources - Processes main resources.
processTestResources - Processes test resources.
```

Comment: Using the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) `apply plugin: 'application'`, implicitly applies the `Distribution plugin` which causes the following dependency chain: `build` -> `assemble` -> `shadowDistTar` -> `shadowJar`. This way calling on `gradle build` generates the fatJar I was expecting

Comment: thank you very much, it worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The 'build' task in Gradle is commonly mistaken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535258/gradle-build-task-confusion) for a task that builds all tasks in a project.  The 'build' task is actually provided by the java-base plugin and includes the following tasks:

```
compileJava, processResources, classes, jar, assemble, compileTestJava, processTestResources, testClasses, test, and check
```

Instead of running 'gradle build' I recommend the use of defaultsTasks

```
`defaultTasks 'build', 'shadowJar'`
```

Putting that line in your build.gradle will allow Gradle to be invoked without arguments such that both build and shadowJar are both run.

```
> gradle
```

I am not familiar with the shadowJar plugin, but if it exposes a task named shadowJar, the use of a dependsOn line in build.gradle could simplify the defaultTasks line.

```
project.tasks.shadowJar.dependsOn build
```

simplifies the defaultTasks line to

```
defaultTasks 'shadowJar'
```